# Keycloak LOGIN_ERROR when accessed through iFrame

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-gatekeeper, keycloak-connect, keycloak-nodejs-connect

Facing issue with Keycloak login when trying to access it using iFrame. I am getting following error:

```
2020-08-29 04:06:50,976 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-9654) type=LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=34d62e4f-f267-4f1a-8ec7-075e5046543b, clientId=null, userId=null, ipAddress=192.168.66.183, error=invalid_code
```

Its working fine when trying to access it via chrome browser,

```
2020-08-29 04:08:44,310 INFO  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-9658) type=LOGIN, realmId=34d62e4f-f267-4f1a-8ec7-075e5046543b, clientId=dxp-frontend, userId=6db38019-c323-4071-abc2-a39c705ed122, ipAddress=192.168.66.183, auth_method=openid-connect, auth_type=code, redirect_uri=https://dxp-model1.devopnet.in.telstra.com.au/csrtb/, consent=no_consent_required, code_id=ac77dc9d-9237-4c17-b74d-9f3c9582ebbd, username=dxpcsr1, authSessionParentId=ac77dc9d-9237-4c17-b74d-9f3c9582ebbd, authSessionTabId=3K3KgKVc2bc
2020-08-29 04:08:45,811 INFO  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-9658) type=CODE_TO_TOKEN, realmId=34d62e4f-f267-4f1a-8ec7-075e5046543b, clientId=dxp-frontend, userId=6db38019-c323-4071-abc2-a39c705ed122, ipAddress=192.168.66.183, token_id=15905d22-c77f-4f6d-bce4-63c36ed04f0b, grant_type=authorization_code, refresh_token_type=Refresh, scope='openid profile email', refresh_token_id=a0b3437b-c2b3-4179-ad24-833459a847db, code_id=ac77dc9d-9237-4c17-b74d-9f3c9582ebbd, client_auth_method=client-secret
```

### Additional Information

Using K8 cluster where a single instance of Keycloak is deployed.

Comment: Which browser gives the error? Also after logging in, in your keycloak object, do you still see the access_token and refresh_token or they are disappeared from the object?

Comment: I am getting the exact same issue running tests in cypress (effectively an iframe).

The browser used under the hood is Chrome. In my case there's no token at all as the authentication flow isn't completed and redirection back to the site does not happen. @Ziko

Comment: Has this been resolved by somebody?